# Mysql select user_ID and use these to construct INSERT statement, possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to unite these two mysql commands?

I need `user_id` from the first sql command, to be used inside the `INSERT` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = "wp_capabilities";


INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES ('user_id', 'wp_s2member_auto_eot_time', 1366286009),
       ('user_id', 'wp_s2member_paid_registration_times', 'a:2:{s:5:"level";s:10:"1366285409";s:6:"level1";s:10:"1366285409";}');
```

First statement will return list of user_id's which can be rather long. I'd like for EACH of these id's INSERT to add respective 2 rows.

I could probably write a php script to do the same, put first list in an array and than do for and run every INSERT using php. But I'd like to learn a bit more about sql. Is it possible what I'm trying to achieve?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your table wp_usermeta have any other columns? Does it have a primary key or some other index?

(I'm sorry about asking for clarification in an "answer", but the system does not let me add comments to other people's question - yet.
As soon as you add some clarification, I will revise this "answer" to be actual answer to your question.)

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna update my question with screenshot of DB table.